# Only get direct text from tags BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working on parsing an HTML document and I want to get specific tags and use them separately to other tags but I am finiding issues such as tags within tags. Could someone please advise how to get only the

tag contents in this and not include the  tag contents?

```
<p> I want this text <b> I want to parse this separately </b> I also want this text </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NavigableString](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) for that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '''<p> I want this text1 <b> I want to parse this separately1 </b> I also want this text1 </p>
<p> I want this text2 <b> I want to parse this separately2 </b> I also want this text2 </p>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    outer_text = ' '.join([x.strip() for x in p if isinstance(x, NavigableString)])
    print(outer_text)
    inner_text = p.b.text.strip()
    print(inner_text)
```

Output:

> I want this text1 I also want this text1
>   I want to parse this separately1
>   I want this text2 I also want this text2
>   I want to parse this separately2

Comment: great thank you, is there a way of implementing this into a loop so that it does the same for all <p> tags in the whole document?

Comment: Yes, you can. Check the edit. And feel free to accept this answer if it solved your question.

Comment: thank you, I am still getting some <a> and <li> tags within my result do you know why?

Comment: You've not provided that html, so I can't say anything without actually seeing it.

Comment: <p>Here are the results:
  <ul class="lis">
    <li>12minutes</li>
    <li>26minutes</li>
  </ul>
</p>

Comment: I'm not getting those using this `' '.join([x.strip() for x in p if isinstance(x, NavigableString)])`. Only `Here are the results: ` as the output.

Comment: I have just noticed the reason for this is because there is a commented section within the html, so it is <!-- <p>Here are the results: <ul class="lis"> <li>12minutes</li> <li>26minutes</li> </ul> </p> --!> is there a reason this makes a difference?

Comment: Scraping contents from a comment is out of scope for this question. There are answers for that on SO. You're diverting a bit too much from your original question.